# Formula to display the current week

Tags: apex, formula, datetime, calendar

Is there a formula to display the calendar week

```
I want to display the following for the 2nd week of FEB,2013
eg: 02/10/2013 to 02/16/2013 
and for 3rd as : 
    02/17/2013 to 02/23/2013
```

I want to display the date range, not week1 week2 format

Any pointers would be greatly appriciated, I want a formula not apex code thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TEXT(MONTH(TODAY() - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(DAY(TODAY() - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(YEAR(TODAY() - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ ' to ' + 
TEXT(MONTH((TODAY() + 7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(DAY((TODAY() + 7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(YEAR((TODAY() + 7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
```

which on today's date (02/14/2013), would return:

> 2/10/2013 to 2/17/2013

I utilized the [formula provided in this post](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tam) to get the current offset on the day of the week. Using that, I just subtracted from today. Unfortunately, you wanted the date formatted outside of the base format of a date which would be `2013-02-14`. To take account for that, I had to do some manipulation and just pull in the month, day, and year of the date.