# Calendar Week Date Range as a formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, calendar

Is there anyway to modify this to look at a different date versus Today? Such as a custom date field?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Is there a formula to display the calendar week 
I want to display the following for the 2nd week of FEB,2013
eg: 02/10/2013 to 02/16/2013 
and for 3rd as : 
    02/17/2013 to 02/23/2013

I want to display the date range, not week1 week2 format

Any pointers would be greatly appriciated, I want a formula not apex code thanks in advance :)

apex formula datetime calendar

---

```
TEXT(MONTH(TODAY() - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(DAY(TODAY() - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(YEAR(TODAY() - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ ' to ' + 
TEXT(MONTH((TODAY() + 7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(DAY((TODAY() + 7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
+ '/' +
TEXT(YEAR((TODAY() + 7) - MOD(TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
```

which on today's date (02/14/2013), would return:

2/10/2013 to 2/17/2013

---

Comment: To provide more insight, this is related to a separate question on this site - Formula to display the current week- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8514/605

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, [`TODAY()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)

> returns the current date as a date data type.

To get the below function to work with a custom field, you should simply be able to modify it and change `TODAY()` to the name of your custom field (**Note:** this field has to be of a [`Date`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) data type).

```
TEXT(MONTH(Custom_Field__c - MOD(Custom_Field__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7))) 
+ '/' + 
TEXT(DAY(Custom_Field__c - MOD(Custom_Field__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7))) 
+ '/' + 
TEXT(YEAR(Custom_Field__c - MOD(Custom_Field__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
 + ' to ' + 
TEXT(MONTH((Custom_Field__c + 7) - MOD(Custom_Field__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
 + '/' + 
TEXT(DAY((Custom_Field__c + 7) - MOD(Custom_Field__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
 + '/' + 
TEXT(YEAR((Custom_Field__c + 7) - MOD(Custom_Field__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is the corrected formula 
Formula return is Text 
For Saturday and Sunday - The range will be in the same week like if its 4/26 , it will show record in the range of 4/20 - 4/24

CASE(MONTH(DateValue(CreatedDate) - MOD(DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,8),7)), 
1, "January", 
2, " February",
3, "March",
4, "April",
5, "May",
6, "June",
7, "July",
8, "August",
9, "September",
10, "October",
11, "November",
12, "December",
NULL)

+" "+

TEXT(DAY(DateValue(CreatedDate) - MOD(DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900,1,8),7)))

+" - "+

CASE(MONTH(CASE(CASE( MOD(  DateValue(CreatedDate)  - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3,
"Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday","ERROR"),
"Sunday", DateValue(CreatedDate) - 2,
"Monday", DateValue(CreatedDate) + 4,
"Tuesday", DateValue(CreatedDate) + 3,
"Wednesday", DateValue(CreatedDate) + 2,
"Thursday", DateValue(CreatedDate) + 1,
"Friday", DateValue(CreatedDate),
"Saturday", DateValue(CreatedDate)- 1,
NULL)), 
1, "January", 
2, " February",
3, "March",
4, "April",
5, "May",
6, "June",
7, "July",
8, "August",
9, "September",
10, "October",
11, "November",
12, "December",
NULL)

+" "+

TEXT(
DAY(CASE(MOD(DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 
0, DateValue(CreatedDate) - 1, 
1, DateValue(CreatedDate) - 2, 
2, DateValue(CreatedDate) + 4, 
3, DateValue(CreatedDate) + 3, 
4, DateValue(CreatedDate) + 2, 
5, DateValue(CreatedDate) + 1, 
6, DateValue(CreatedDate), 
TODAY()))
)